# Query azure custom metrics of log based metrics

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

I want to get the records of a custom metric under log-based metric namespace.

Via Portal, I was able to go to Application insights and see the graph for the custom metric.

But how to do the same via Python SDK? I was unable to find any resources on fetching custom metrics.

I have the resource ID, metric name, interval and aggregation, with these details, I should be able to fetch the associated records. My usecase is to fetch the average of the custom metric in the last 15 minutes duration.

The custom metric is based on Eventhub.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/metrics/get?tabs=HTTP#uri-parameters - this documentation provides the API for custom metrics as well